# asp.net 4.0 c# "source code is different from the original version" ALSO 404'ing on me

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

net project that runs but gives me a 404 when I click on links and 1/2 the images are showing up. Also when I try to debug the issue I get "source code is different from the original version" on the break points. I have tried:

- Clean
- Rebuild 
  Did not work.

I added a page handler to the web.config did not work.
I deleted the bin files and my project went crazy and found a 258 bugs including the global asax thinking that the Inherits is wrong. So I restored the files, something is up with the project I just don't know what.

Its visual studio 2010 running local on a windows 7 computer all my other sites work just fine so I don't think its a iis thing.

Thanks for any help!
Tim

Comment: Are you running the site through Visual Studio's web server or through IIS?  This may make a difference if you reference stuff outside of the project and run through Visual Studio's web server I'd think.

Comment: Visual Studio, I am not referencing anything outside the project

Comment: @user1221399 "Rebuild did not work" that would be why it's giving you a "source code is different from the original version" error. Try restarting visual studio, rebooting your computer, and giving it another try. Sometimes I've noticed the compiler can start acting strange for some reason. Run it As Administrator too and see if that helps.

Comment: I did try that also sorry I should have specified.

Comment: I created a new project and added the old files in to the project and everything is working now. 
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning your solution, if that doesn't work delete the bin and obj directories and rebuild.  Sometimes an old dll is hanging around in there that may have classes with the same name.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project and added the old files in to the project and everything is working now.